# DL180 G6 12 bay backplane connections

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP DL180 G6 12 bay server with a P212 Raid card. I can not open the server to see inside but I would like to know what connections the backplane has. Right now it has 6 1TB hdd attached. According to the HP raid array configuration program; the 6 drives are on one SF-8087 connection. (i can not find any hp documents about the backplane)

What I would like to do is add another HP raid card with 2x SAS connectors to create a 8 drive raid 10. Is this possible or how is the backplane set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HP ProLiant DL180 G6 12-bay LFF drive backplane has a single 4-lane [SFF-8087](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg) SAS connector (See *#4* on the graphic below).

The backplane has an integrated SAS expander that accommodates the 12 bays. The expander actually supports 14-ports, with two backplane-mounted SATA connectors to interface to the rear-mount 2-drive cage option (HP #488234-B21).

If you're interested in replacing your Smart Array P212 controller, you can safely use a [Smart Array P410](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13201_na/13201_na.html) or [Smart Array P812](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13558_na/13558_na.html) controller to accomplish your goal. Only one [SFF-8087](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg) port will be used.

[image]

Also see the [DL180 G6 Service Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01727924/c01727924.pdf).