# Proliant dl 180 g6 install normal SATA drives

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sata, hp-smart-array

I have a Proliant DL180 G6 with problems in the P410 controller.

I want to instal normal SATA drives in the server. I see the mother has 4 SATA slots but I can´t find how to power the SATA drives because the power unit does nott have SATA power cables.

Comment: How many drive bays does your DL180 G6 have in the front of the server?

Comment: You need to buy HP branded drives which come in their own caddies, anything else isn't supported and we have routine tales on this site of people using their own drives and losing data down the line.

Comment: You've gotta buy HP branded drives.  It's a running business expense.  Either pony up, or you'll lose your warranty, and any possible chance of reliability.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to buy HP drives for this server. However, there is a backplane on most DL180 G6 models. The number of drive bays will help us determine which model you have. One the low-end, there is a 4-drive SATA model with leverages the motherboard headers rather than hotswap backplane connections. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/404545/dl180-g6-12-bay-backplane-connections/404547#404547

Comment: the server has 8 drive bays in the front. It was running with 3 HP SAS drive 300 Gb. i have a second server and install these drives in my second server.another

Comment: @ewwhite - still makes vendor support a little more iffy, right?

Comment: Now i just want to install regural SATA drives using the sata ports in the motherboard. Not using the drive controller because is broken, so i want to install normas regular Sata drives in the server, with no RAID, just for storage.

Comment: the server is out of warranty so no problem with that.

Comment: You can't use standard desktop drives. They have to be the hotplug ones so they plug into the backplane.

Comment: You can use plain SATA drives. They plug into a SAS backplane just fine. You only need caddies, which you can find on eBay for $10. Performance might be degraded by using non-HP drives. I've heard of some drives not working with HP SA controllers too, but have not encountered any problems myself.

Comment: so i cant´t use standard desktop drives without the backlane? So why the mother comes with four sata ports.

Comment: Why would you want to use the server without the backplane? The 4 SATA ports can be plugged into a 4xSATA Reverse SFF-8087 cable (4 plugs into mobo, 1 plug into backplane).

Comment: because here in Argentina, i can´t find that cable.

Comment: If you're going to yank the backplane you'll need a different HP/Common Slot Power Supply that has SATA (or molex/LP4 and an adapter) power plugs available.  I'm not aware of any way to adapt the 10-pin power cord that feed the backplane to SATA.

Comment: Also, have you seen this advisory?  You may just need to update the backplane firmware to resolve problems with the P410.  http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03011608

Comment: i saw that post, but i dónt have that problem. i also have only have 3 SAS drives, no SATA drives.